# Finding Points on a NURB using OpenGL and GLU

Tags: c++, opengl, window, glu

I am attempting to draw a shape by revolving a NURB around an axis to generate the points using OpenGL. I am able to render a NURB using `gluNurbsCurve`, but I would like to find the interpolated points along the NURB to use in the rotation.

I have not been able to find a way to do this, what I have turned up is that [the callback interface](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~haoz/teaching/htmlman/nurbscallback.html) should expose what I am looking for but [windows doesn't support that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It seems that [someone else](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/161433-Windows-GLU-Implementation-NURBS) has come up with a solution, but never posted it.

Is there a known workaround or a way to access the data structure directly to get the information out that I need?

Comment: :( Why do people on forums never follow through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dissect [Mesa's NURBS implementation](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/glu/tree/src/libnurbs).

Or use the (deprecated) [GL feedback mechanism](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter13.html#name2) to slurp out the generated geometry.